# Considering a second degree to be a patent bar eligible lawyer--masters or bachelor?

Tags: masters, second-degree

I've always had an interest in math/physics, but ended up pursuing classics instead in undegrad (not remotely related I know). After undergrad I got my J.D., and have spent the last 3 years practicing law. I recently shifted into patent litigation (lawsuits about if someone stole your patent), but in talking with the patent attorneys I am very, very interested in patent prosecution (filing patents) for personal and professional reasons.

However, to prosecute patents you have to be registered before the patent board, which generally means you need a bachelors in a hard science or engineering, though with the right credit distribution a Masters is also fine. Technically you can take the exam without a degree, just the requisite credits, but most firms I've spoken to are not interested in hiring a patent bar certified attorney without a degree they can show to clients, so SOME form of degree would basically be required. However the firms I've spoken to have all indicated that a Masters instead of a Bachelors would be fine.

I'm seriously considering going for a second degree, either a second bachelors or a masters, in order to shift into patent prosecution. However, I'm not sure which would be better to pursue at this point in my life (the Masters would be patent bar eligible as long as I have enough total credits in specific fields... they have a whole guide sheet on this on the USPTO website).

I took through multi-variable calc and gen chem/gen physics in undergrad, so I might be able to get enough classes for admission to a Masters in physics (as much as I love astronautics at this point I'm assuming engineering is out of the question, so Physics seems my best bet). However, I know that programs that take non-science undergrad degrees aren't as common, and probably would be harder to get into. Alternatively I could see about just getting a second undergraduate, though it seems that may take longer, I think?  A shorter or part time is better, obviously, though financially I could take a few years off to chase the degree if needed, esp as studying for it might be hard to do while practicing. Basically I'm not sure which degree direction to start looking.

EDIT: I should add that while this isn't a career in academia immediately, my long term goal is to teach in law, for which one of the common routes is to practice for a while. Probably would get an SJD some time in the future. Law is weird.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Few MSE programs are ABET accredited so you'll need to take the FE exam anyway. If your end goal is to qualify for the patent bar you'd probably be better off doing a BSE.

Comment: I understand you situation from the question, but I think you need to better format it into a question, so that one can know what would qualify as an answer. For instance, what exactly is your goal? Being able to file patents as soon as possible? Figure out which is the easiest admission path into a hard sciences undergrad course? By the way, if you are a lawyer, you might be closer to a Production Engineer than you are to a Physicist. Are you asking for fields that would accommodate you (this is usually considered off topic here)?